# During Test Programming I have Created a File With a Faulty Filename - It Now Wont Delete

Tags: windows, file, filesystems

**ANSWER:** I have found a way of doing it. Go into the directory and type `del *.*`. That works. Note: typing `del C:\wamp64\www\MyTest` does not work. Nor does `del background.jpg,..`

**QUESTION:**

During a test programming (NodeWebkit) I have created a file with a faulty file name. The file name I have created is:

```
background.jpg,..
```

Yes, that is a comma and two periods at the end.

I cannot seem to be able to delete this file now, even in `File Explorer`.

Please help, how can I delete this file?

**EDIT:**

When I use the command line I get the following:

```
C:\wamp64\www\MyTest>del background.jpg,..
Could Not Find C:\wamp64\www\MyTest\background.jpg
C:\wamp64\www\MyTest\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
```

When I type `y` and `return` it does nothing.

Also note: When I do `dir` in the command line it includes `10/10/2017 17:51 82,792 background.jpg,..`

Comment: Have you tried the command line? Del ?

Comment: Yes I tried `del background.jpg,..` but that does not work. I think the comma and periods is confusing things.

Comment: Yep @Carcigenicate, when I do `dir` in the command line it includes `10/10/2017  17:51             82,792 background.jpg,..`

Comment: In CMD you can easily create and delete such a file. For example, `type nul > "\\?\%cd%\background.jpg,.."`, and then `del "\\?\%cd%\background.jpg,.."`.

Comment: How did you end up creating a file with trailing dots? The user-mode runtime library strips off the trailing dots from the final component of a path -- since it's trying to emulate 1980s MS-DOS. It is, however, a legal filename in the NT namespace, so creating and opening such a name is possible with the "\\?\" prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: I have found a way of doing it. Go into the directory and type del *.*. That works. Note: typing del C:\wamp64\www\MyTest does not work. Nor does del background.jpg,..